# Add a string property to a linklabel?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am currently making an "app launcher" which reads a text file line by line.  Each line is a path to a useful program somewhere else on my pc.  A link label is automatically made for each path (i.e. each line) in the text file.

I would like the .Text property of the link label to be an abbreviated form of the path (i.e. just the file name, not the whole path).  I have found out how to shorten the string in this way (so far so good !)

However, I would also like to store the full path somewhere - as this is what my linklabel will need to link to.  In Javascript I could pretty much just add this property to linklabel like so:   mylinklabel.fullpath=line;   (where line is the current line as we read through the text file, and fullpath is my "custom" property that I would like to try and add to the link label.  I guess it needs declaring, but I am not sure how.

Below is the part of my code which creates the form, reads the text file line by line and creates a link label for the path found on each line:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   //on form load
{
  //System.Console.WriteLine("hello!");
  int counter = 0;
  string line;
  string filenameNoExtension;
  string myfile = @"c:\\users\matt\desktop\file.txt";

  //string filenameNoExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myfile);


  // Read the file and display it line by line.
  System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(myfile);
  while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    //MessageBox.Show(line);   //check whats on each line


    LinkLabel mylinklabel = new LinkLabel(); 
    filenameNoExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(line);  //shortens the path to just the file name without extension
    mylinklabel.Text = filenameNoExtension;
    //string fullpath=line;      //doesn't work
    //mylinklabel.fullpath=line;   //doesn't work
    mylinklabel.Text = filenameNoExtension;  //displays the shortened path
    this.Controls.Add(mylinklabel);
    mylinklabel.Location = new Point(0, 30 + counter * 30);
    mylinklabel.AutoSize = true;
    mylinklabel.VisitedLinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    mylinklabel.LinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;



    mylinklabel.Click += new System.EventHandler(LinkClick);


    counter++;
  }

  file.Close();

}
```

So, how can I store a full path as a string inside the linklabel for use in my onclick function later on?

Answer (score 1):

You could derive a new custom class or you could use a secondary data store for your additional info the easiest solution would be to use a dictionary.

```
dictonary<string,string> FilePaths = new dictonary<string,string>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   //on form load
{
    ...

    FilePath[filenameNoExtension] = line;
}
```

You Can Access the Path

```
FilePath[mylinklabel.Tex]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to have a method that truncates your string (and even adds "..."). You can then store the full path in the [Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.link.tag.aspx) of the Linklabel. And here's an example of the first part (truncating the text).

```
public static string Truncate(this string s, int maxLength)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || maxLength <= 0)
        return string.Empty;
    else if (s.Length > maxLength)
        return s.Substring(0, maxLength) + "...";
    else
        return s;
}
```

Hope that helps some